# Google maps markers are hidden behind each other

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a problem with markers hidden behind other markers.
The problem occurs when the addresses are too close to each other. e.g. `street 20, street 22`.

Changing `zIndex` will not help, because that is just "stacking".
How can I "float" the markers so that they are all visible on the map?

Comment: Do you use any database to store the coords?

Comment: Yeah. The only solution I see, is to controll each geolocation and if two are to close, move one a tiny bit.

Comment: Yeap.In a similar problem i did exactly this.Before insertion of a place inside the database i checked in an area around if already a place existed and if existed near enough i slightly move them.

Comment: Would you happend to still have that code? :)

Comment: That is why i asked you what dbms you are using beacause i used postgis and i use functions specific for that db.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you look into marker clustering.

<s>http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/advanced_example.html</s>

**UPDATE:**

Google now support marker cluserting via a native library: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Comment: I've looked at it and that will not solve my problem. It only clusters markers when zoomed out. Once you zoom in, the markers will be visible and stacked on top of each other.

Comment: The hyperlink is out-of-date. It's good that you mentioned the name of the feature, "marker clustering".

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW, I have updated the answer with a new link.

Answer (score 2):

is this any use to you - it's called 'Spiderfier':

<s>http://blog.mackerron.com/2011/06/22/overlapping-marker-spiderfier/</s>
https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Answer (score 0):

It might help to use smaller markers. When I had this problem, I changed the size of my marker images from 20x34 px down to 20x20 px.

Comment: I tested this and it doesn't help. The location is still the same and the icons are the same size, hence they will be hidden under each other.

Answer (score 0):

So,you can use [mysql spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html) and **MBRContains(RectangleAroundYourPoint,GeometryColumnOfYourTable)**

-if of course your table have a geometry column which is easy(upon creation you choose i.e. point as the column type,and when performing an insertion you have to do it with [GeomFromText](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/geometry-property-functions.html))-

to check if another place exist within that rectangle and if it is move the newcoming place until the **mbrcontains** return false or something like that.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I use marker clusterer and had the same problem. I add a small random number to coordinates. I do not want to change the locations of markers so much therefore in satellite mode problem still exists but in map mode we can zoom much more.
This may not be a good solution but good enough for my application.